# Url Rewriter works on localhost but not on production server

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, urlrewriter.net

I've gotten URLRewriter to work on my localhot perfectly, but on production I get 404 errors.

I'm using IIS 6, and from what I read this should just work.

Here is what i have in my web.config:

```
<rewriter>
  <rewrite url="~/(\d+)$"       to="~/Items/Details.aspx?ItemId=$1" />
  <rewrite url="~/Items/(\d+)$" to="~/Items/Details.aspx?ItemIId=$1" />
</rewriter>

<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />


<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>

</httpModules>
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and solved it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the UrlRewriter DLL is installed properly on your production server? Are you seeing any errors in the Windows event log?

Comment: Installed?  It goes in the bin. What installation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite url="~/Items/(\d+)$" to="~/Items/Details.aspx?ItemIdId=$1" />
```

Is that GET parameter meant to be ItemId? Cos at the moment it's ItemIdId.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nah just a typo, like i said, works on localhost, not on production

Answer (score 0):

Its because you need to setup wildcard mapping on the production server. IIS6 only runs certain file formats such as .aspx etc, but doesnt map extensionless urls to the asp.net pipeline.

This tutorial will answer your question:

- http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2007/07/27/Configure-IIS-for-Wildcard-Extensions-in-ASP.NET.aspx

NOTE: You will need remote desktop access to your server so this isn't possible in shared hosting environments unless your host is willing to set this up on your behalf.

Comment: Oops, only just realised this question is a year old... :P